# Cannot launch AVD in a emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, xml-parsing, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I cannot run emulator and get this error(AS 2.3.3):

> Output:
>
> emulator: WARNING: encryption is off.
>
> Hax is enabled.
>
> Hax ram_size 0x60000000
>
> HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
>
> none.xml: 1: parser error: Space is required after Public Identifier.
>
> <! DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HYML 4.0 Transitional//EN">